# Condition on blocked account java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a problem. I am writing a test program to log the user into the system. I encountered a problem and I do not know how to solve it. Namely, the user gives the login and password and press the confirm button. It sometimes happens that the account is locked and the user can not log in then. Can someone help me how to write such a condition condition that when pressed approve we will get a message in the console that the account is locked? And if logging is possible then this code snippet will execute.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_id9']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")).click();
```

All code:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys(userName.get(i));

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password.get(i));

        driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='_id9']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Can not anyone help? :)

Comment: Provide more info as: 1. You spoke about `press the confirm button` next you mentioned `when pressed approve`, are they 2 different buttons or same button? 2. You mentioned `message in the console`, which message are you referring to? Is the error message of the Application something like `Invalid username/password` or `Account is Locked`?

Comment: That may be so. The user enters the login and password and presses the Submit button. When pressed, the user logs on to the system or logs on because he has entered a bad password. If you gave the wrong password when the database gets update positioning flag = 1, the account blocked.

Comment: I am downloading the login and password from the file and it is entered in the "userID" and "password" fields. Then the user presses the "Submit" button and either logs in to the system because the password is valid, or fails to log in because the password is incorrect.

Comment: `either logs in to the system because the password is valid, or fails to log in because the password is incorrect` makes sense to me. So what is your next step which you want to achieve through Selenium? Thanks

Comment: I don't have a way to validate if you are using a correct xpath and your xpath looks vulnerable to me. Try to use logical xpath instead of absolute xpath. Thanks

Comment: If I do not log into the system, then I want the login and password fields to be locked in the database. But write to the database know how to do, just do not know how to write the condition

Comment: `**if (driver.findElement (By.id ("Submit"))) == wrong** {update to database}
Else {
driver.findElement (By.xpath (".//*[@ id = '_ ID9'] / table / tbody / tr [2] / td [1] / table [1] / tbody / tr [5] / td [ 2] / a ')). click ();
         Driver.manage () .timeouts (). ImplicitlyWait (100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         Thread.Sleep (6000);
         Driver.manage () .timeouts (). ImplicitlyWait (100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}`

Comment: Please format your code properly. You can remove the lines containing `ImplicitlyWait` and `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: ** if (driver.findElement (By.id ("Submit"))) == wrong ** {update to database}
Else {
Driver.findElement (By.xpath (".////[ id = '_ ID9'] / table / tbody / tr [2] / td [1] / table [1] / tbody / tr [5] [2] / a ')). Click ();
}

Comment: 1. With wrong credentials the system won't let you log in, how can you update the database? 2. What are trying to do in the Else block explain in plain terms please. Thanks

Comment: 1. I download a list of logins and passwords from the database. I save the records in the file and later download the login and password one by one and log on to the system. Some passwords for logins stored in the file are incorrect because the user, for example, did not change the password within 30 days. Then the account is blocked. Then the database update is done in the column IsDisabled = true.

Comment: 2. The else block is a piece of code. After logging in, the user moves to the password change screen where the password is changed. If the user changes the password, then the database in the column IsDisabled = false.